# Jupyter opens .ipynb as plain text instead of showing interactive cells

Tags: json, file, text, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My laptop was shut down when it ran out of battery while I was editing the ipnyb file in the Jupyter notebook, now when I am trying to open my ipnyb file in jupyter notebook (anaconda setup), the file is shown as plain text instead of interactive cells.

The file content as shown below: `{ "cells": [ { "cell_type": "markdown", "metadata": {}, "source": [ "### This is a file python file'\n", "\n",` .................

Is there any way to open the ipnyb file back in the interactive cell mode?